# Do moderator mass-retag actions change the attribution of who created a tag?

Tags: support, tags, moderator-abilities, tag-creation

Who gets credit for creating a tag that was created by a moderator's behind-the-scenes retag? Is it the same between if the tag actually was new versus the tag was empty?

It's not a strict retag action like non-moderators do, so I don't know if the moderator gets attributed. And on the Gaming site, I recently earned the Taxonomist badge for the [game-rec] tag, despite myself only having created its predecessor [game-recommendations] during the private Beta. Jeff did the time warp (*again*) to revise the tag's name, which appears to have shifted the attribution to me. I don't know if Jeff's chronomanipulatory abilities are the same as what normal diamonds can accomplish with their tool, so it made me curious what happens in the diamond moderator version.

Comment: On that note, that badge is probably the only badge I have ever earned which has actually depressed me. Not even Tumbleweed was depressing.

Comment: btw, I disagree with that rename, game-rec sounds to me like "recording", but that's a topic for [gaming meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Juan http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/517/why-was-game-recomendations-shortened-to-game-rec. The confusion with recording was also brought up [when I created the first rendition of the monster](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/217/looking-for-game-tag-vs-identify-this-game-tag/218#218).

Comment: Follow-up question: Does anyone know if Taxonomist is a one-time-only badge?  It seems like it should be awarded for each tag you create, but I can't seem to find anyone who has more than one.

Comment: @Bill: I always thought it is one time only. The badge description also does not mention "multiple times". If you have showed that you're a taxonomist, you are one, period.

Comment: I always thought you'd get one for every tag you created (that qualifies) @bill @lady

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we do a retag where we're merging two tags that already exist, the original person who created the target tag gets the credit.

If a tag doesn't exist and we create it then do a merge with that tag as a target, we get the credit for creating it, resulting in a Taxonomist badge being awarded.  (This is how I got mine on SO.)

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: I didn't do it on purpose, I swear.  :)  Honestly though, I do feel bad about being awarded such a hard-to-get badge in that way.  Not everyone has that opportunity, so it really isn't fair.  I wouldn't object if it were removed.

Comment: And if you *accidentally* wipe out a famous tag by renaming it with a typo (wanting originally to get rid of the typo), you have to create it again, and do the opposite rename. It gives you the taxonomist tag too. I know a guy this happened to, recently.

Comment: @Gno: Does his name begins with "Gno"?

Comment: @Lady - I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Hah, I actually remember the retag-request which probably earned you that badge.

Comment: @upi: I take that as "YES!"