# Does "created tag" equate to "first use"?

Tags: discussion, tags, moderators, tag-creation

I have read through many posts, most importantly:

[How does one find which tags they created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10888/how-does-one-find-which-tags-they-created)

[Find out which question/answer awarded you the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge)

[Do moderator mass-retag actions change the attribution of who created a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57668/do-moderator-mass-retag-actions-change-the-attribution-of-who-created-a-tag)

And I'm pretty sure I understand all that.

**What I don't understand** and can't find anywhere:

If a Moderator edits a post adding/creating tags *per the tag-suggestions by the OP* within that post, who could inevitably receive the Taxonomist credit? Is it actually who "created" the tags, or to the user of the OP that used that tag regardless of who created those tags?

This is the post that sparked my interest, on Astronomy: [Could black holes be creators of dark matter?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1698/will-the-jwst-be-able-to-capture-something-similar-to-or-better-than-the-hudf)

*Feel free to move this to meta.astronomy but I thought the maturity of meta.stackoverflow would be more suited in concisely answering this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the case where the OP writes something similar to the following in a comment, or in the  question itself, then the creator is the user who effectively adds the new tag as suggested/required by the OP.

> By the way, I would like to take the question with [tag-name], but I cannot. Can anybody add it for me?

If you are referring to the case of a user suggesting an edit for a question, and adding a new tag that is kept when the suggestion is approved (which means the suggested edit is not improved to remove that tag), then who suggested the edit is the creator of the tag.
This last case can happen only when the user who suggested the edit has the reputation to create new tags. The user can retag a question using the "retag" link, and not suggesting a new edit, but there are cases where the question needs to be edited to change its body, and add a new tag; in those cases, the user click on the "edit" link to edit both at once.

Comment: The first two cases answer my question. I fell into the first and was the OP :_(

Comment: Actually, I am describing just two cases: When the OP asks to somebody else to add a new tag, and when a user who can create new tags suggests an edit that adds a new tag. `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

Suggesting a tag has no effect--how could it?  The SE code isn't going to analyze every retag or even creation to see whether someone suggested it first.  If you (not necessarily a mod, anyone with the tag creation privilege [500 rep]) create the tag by being the first to use it (yes, that is the definition), then you get the credit.

Comment: `how could it?` well... `The SE code isn't going to analyze every retag or even creation to see whether someone suggested it first` could have not been the case. Also, if it _did_ work in the way I thought probable, I would have assumed it would have been accomplished by the edits.